# Unable to get data from the form in Bootstrap 5 with Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-5, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using Angular and Bootstrap 5, I have this HTML code of a form:

```html
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="genreName"> Tür adı</label>
  <div *ngIf="!enterTheGenre" class="form-group">
    <select class="form-select">
      <option [value]="genre.genreName" *ngFor="let genre of genres">
        {{ genre.genreName }}
      </option>
      <option>Tür ekle</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

ts file:

```js
addBook() {
    let bookModel:Book = Object.assign({}, this.bookAddForm.value);
}
```

But I can't get data from the form.

`genreName` data always null. I use `select` for `genreName`, but for others, I use `input`, so I can get data from input, but I can't get it from the form.

[image: Console log]

I changed value parameters like `[value]="genre"` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if you are doing template driven forms or reactive forms in your code, but either way it appears you haven't bound anything to your select.

If you are doing **template driven forms**, you need to bind to either the `ngModel` or subscribe to the `changes` event on the `<select>` element.

Example 1:

```
<select class="form-select" [(ngModel)]="book.genre">
```

Example 2:

```
<select class="form-select" (change)="onGenreChange($event)">
```

For more info on building a **template driven form**, please see [Angular's Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

If you are using **reactive forms**, you need to add a `formControl` on the `<select>` element

Example 3:

```
<select class="form-select" [formControl]="bookAddForm">
```

For more information about **reactive forms**, please see [Angular's docuentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#adding-a-basic-form-control)